# Remove the thin origin line from the background of a Flex graph

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I wish to remove the thin origin line from the background of a Flex graph. I have converted one of axes to a Category axis and an origin line remains, that is now unwanted.

The following seems to remove all the vertical lines as well as the origin

```
<mx:backgroundElements>
  <mx:GridLines verticalShowOrigin="false"/>
</mx:backgroundElements>
```

While

```
<mx:backgroundElements>
</mx:backgroundElements>
```

removes all background lines1

Comment: I hate that line. You can try to mask it out. At least I haven't found a better way to achieve the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky way, there might be better way. I achieved that by doing this :

```
<mx:Stroke weight="1" alpha="0" id="blankStroke"/>
<mx:backgroundElements>
    <mx:Array>
        <mx:GridLines direction="horizontal" 
           horizontalOriginStroke="{blankStroke}" 
           horizontalShowOrigin="true"/>        
    </mx:Array>
</mx:backgroundElements>
```

Just make the alpha of the stroke as 0. :-P 
There are lots of ways to cheat Flex. ;-)
Please let me know whether this is what you wanted.

Cheers, PK

Comment: It wouldn't allow Array so I removed it and then it wouldn't allow Stroke as it said it was depreciated since 4.0 so I used SolidColorStroke in the Declarations fx block. did not like direction so I removed that as well. And it still doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: okay. actually my code was from 3.0. Right now am not having 4.0 here. Will try it out and post you if I succeeds. Meanwhile I hope someone might turn around with a solution. :-) Cheers

Comment: At least as of 4.5.1, the mx:GridLines properties for `verticalShowOrigin` and `horizontalShowOrigin` work as advertised. I didn't have any problem setting them false and watching them disappear.